# tail recursion sum, power, gcd in prolog?

Tags: recursion, prolog, tail-recursion, greatest-common-divisor

how can I accomplish this:

Give a tail-recursive definition for each of the following predicates.
`power(X,Y,Z)`: XY=Z.
`gcd(X,Y,Z)`: The greatest common divisor of X and Y is Z.
`sum(L,Sum)`: Sum is the sum of the elements in L.

so far I have done this but not sure if that's correct

```
power(_,0,1) :- !.
power(X,Y,Z) :- Y1 is Y - 1,power(X,Y1,Z1),Z is X * Z1.

sum(void,0).
sum(t(V,L,R),S) :- sum(L,S1),sum(R,S2),  S is V + S1 + S2.
```

Comment: If you're not sure it's correct, TEST IT.

Comment: Frank: if you indent text 4 spaces, it will format it as code. Edit your question and give it a try. The orange question mark in the editor toolbar links to a document with other formatting markup.

Answer (score 2):

These are not tail recursive. You can write tail recursive variants by using an accumulator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549943/design-patterns-for-converting-recursive-algorithms-to-iterative-ones/1550188#1550188).

Your sum is over a tree, which is unusual, normally one would use a list. In Prolog [] is the empty list and [X|R] is the pattern for a nonempty list with the head X and the tail R.

Comment: Sir, please can u help me write the power in recursive fashion? I just started learning it and can't do it.Please help me with one of them at least.
Thanks
Frank

Comment: It's your homework, not mine. I'm not even your instructor. Sorry, I won't give you specific solutions, you are supposed to learn thinking for yourself.