# Change recursive function to iterative

Tags: c, iteration

There is a recursive function `f()`.  It is looking at `cond` and then either returning or executing `f()` then `g()`.  Consider `cond` to be an external variable that can be set somewhere else, perhaps in a different thread.

1. If the first five times `cond` is checked, `cond == true`, but the sixth time, `cond == false`, describe the code flow.
2. Because this is recursive, the code could suffer from a stack overflow if `cond == true` for too long.  Fill in the function `iterative_f()` so that the code flow is identical to the code flow in (1).

   ```
   //recursive

   void f()
   {
       if(cond == false)
           return;
       f();
       g();
   }

   //iterative  
   void iterative_f() {

   }
   ```

Comment: So sad to see teachers supplying `boolean_variable == false`!  Please use `if (!cond)` or `if (not cond)` (both equivalent and Standard, though I'm not sure if even MSVC++ 2010 supports `not` - think they're too worried about breaking code where people called their variable "not").

Comment: @Tony: `not` is not a C keyword.

Comment: JeremyP: true - C++ only - I should have checked the question's tags :-/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can every recursion be converted into iteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/931762/), [Design patterns for converting recursive algorithms to iterative ones](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549943/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Since the cond is false the 6th time, the function will in effect execute 5 times. The result is that function g will be executed 5 times.
2. Now you can write the iterative function as follows:

```
    void iterative_f() 
    {
       while(cond)
       {
          g();
       } 
    }
```

Comment: I was asked this in an interview and this was my exact answer. However, the interviewer said that this iterative function would change the sequence in which the function g() gets called. As in the recursive function calls the 5th instance of the function g() first. However, this iterative version would call the 1st instance first.

Comment: Yes that can be a logical argument. But making a sequence of call to a function cannot have a notion of particular ordering.

Comment: Lets put this in a simpler way. For the recursive function, we are not calling 5th instance of function g() first but we are calling function g() for the first time in the 5th call to function f(). As for the iterative function, we are calling function g() for the first time in the first iteration. Does that make sense?