# how to solve 0-1 package problem by iteration?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Design patterns for converting recursive algorithms to iterative ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549943/design-patterns-for-converting-recursive-algorithms-to-iterative-ones)

I can only figure out a recursive way:
how to transform it into iteration?
for simplicity, my recursive way only find the result value.

```
#include<iostream>
//0-1 bag
using namespace std;
int weight[5]={50,30,45,25,5};
int value[5]={200,180,225,200,50};

int valueAfterTake(int objectNO, int bagSpaceLeft)
{
    int take,notTake;
    if(objectNO < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        take = value[objectNO] + valueAfterTake(objectNO - 1,bagSpaceLeft - weight[objectNO]);
        notTake = valueAfterTake(objectNO - 1, bagSpaceLeft);
    }
    if(weight[objectNO] > bagSpaceLeft)
    {
        return notTake;
    }

    if(take > notTake)
    {
        return take;
    }
    else
    {
        return notTake;
    }
}


int main()
{
    cout<<valueAfterTake(4,100)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the "0-1 package problem"?

Comment: I think hes referring to the 0-1 knapsack algorithm

Comment: while,it is 0-1 knapsack algorithm, I am not a native english speaker so I just translated the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you really want, I think this is a duplicate question of [Design patterns for converting recursive algorithms to iterative ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549943/design-patterns-for-converting-recursive-algorithms-to-iterative-ones)

Answer (score 1):

From the algorithm in [0-1 knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) can put everything in a table of i and w.
Make a two diminutional table filled with NO_VALUE constants(-1 or something like that).
Then when you need to get the value for m[i, w] you find what indexes from the table you need, check if their computed(by comparing to NO_VALUE), and computing them if their not.
Here you will gain much less code execution in tradeoff for space because you will never compute the same value twice.
edit:
In addition, from there you can continue to find patterns, like you're always using one row, or one diagonal and such and cut out everything you don't need in the table.