# recursive to iterative

Tags: c

I have this function, and I want to change it to an iterative one. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
#include "list.h"

int count(LINK head)
{

if(head == NULL)
   return 0;
else
   return (1 + count(head -> next));
}
```

Comment: This smells like homework to me. Have you even tried?

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it, and you could too if you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can every recursion be converted into iteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/931762/), [Design patterns for converting recursive algorithms to iterative ones](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549943/)

Answer (score 5):

```
int count(LINK head)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        head = head->next;
        count = count + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```