# Sml folding a tree

Tags: function, tree, sml, fold

I am trying to get the product of a tree by using the fold function so far this is what I have. I am confused on how to use the fold method while transversing the tree

```
datatype 'a bin_tree = Leaf of 'a 
| Node of 'a bin_tree * 'a bin_tree


fun treefold g z Empty = z
| treefold g z (Node (l, x, r)) = g(x, g(treefold g z l, treefold g z r)
```

Comment: There is an inconsistency between your datatype definition, where the `Node` constructor takes 2 arguments, and your use of `Node (l,x,r)` where you seem to think of `Node` as taking 3 arguments. I think that you need to tweak your datatype definition to include a third, middle, argument.

Comment: To add to my last comment, you might need to change your definition of `treefold` instead so that it calls `Node` with 2 arguments. But, whatever you do, it needs to be consistent. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

First, some pointers about what isn't quite in order in your attempt.

1. The base case of your `treefold` function matches against the value constructor `Empty`, but you don't define the `bin_tree` datatype to include an `Empty` value constructor.
2. As John Coleman points out in his comments, you've defined the `Node` value constructor to take a pair, but in your recursive case you match `Node` with a triple. Bearing in mind Simon Shine's excellent answer explaining folds over binary trees, we can probably infer the reason for this: your `treefold` function expects a canonical binary tree (where each node has a value and two branches) but the data structure you defined doesn't implement this structure.  I'm not sure what the data structure you've defined is called, despite giving it a good google (though I think I've implemented it before!).
3. You apply `g` to `z` twice, once down the left branch and once down the right branch. This would mean the value passed in to that place will get included in the fold twice for every branch. I don't imagine that's what you intended.

(1) and (2) should both be caught by the type checker as soon as you try to compile or load your code. You should try this, if you haven't already, and make sure you understand the feedback the type checker provides. It is a very valuable tool.

(3) has to do with the nature of the function you intend to write, and it is only out of order if you didn't mean it.

Here's one way to define a fold over the data structure you defined.

```
structure Tree =
struct
    datatype 'a tree = Leaf of 'a
                     | Node of 'a tree * 'a tree

    fun foldl f x t =
      case t
       of Leaf y => f (x, y)              (* The base case *)
        | Node (treeL, treeR) =>
          let
              val l = foldl f x treeL     (* Recurse down the left branch *)
          in
              foldl f l treeR             (* Recurse down the right branch *)
          end
end
```

Notice that, having put `foldl` here in the `Tree` module, we now how have a function that mirrors the `foldl` function in the `List` structure (and elsewhere):

```
- List.foldl;
val it = fn : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
- Tree.foldl;
val it = fn : ('a * 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b bin_tree -> 'a
```

This would make it easier to parameterize over either lists or trees.

It works like so:

```
- foldl op+ 0 (Node (Leaf 3, Node (Node (Leaf 1, Leaf 2), Leaf 5)));
val it = 11 : int
```

Comment: After reading Simon Shine's answer, I realized I made a mistake in identifying the data structure given in the question with a canonical binary tree. I have subsequently edited my answer to correct this and to acknowledge the difference. If anyone knows what to call this data structure (a tree with values in the leafs but none in the node), please let me know so I can improve my answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

When folding a binary tree,

```
datatype 'a tree = Leaf | Branch of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree
```

you may traverse it in [different ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). Among common strategies you have,

```
(* Pre-order *)
fun treefold_preorder f acc1 Leaf = acc1
  | treefold_preorder f acc1 (Branch (left, a, right)) =
    let val acc2 = treefold_preorder f acc1 left
        val acc3 = f (a, acc2)
        val acc4 = treefold_preorder f acc3 right
    in acc4 end

(* In-order *)
and treefold_inorder f acc1 Leaf = acc1
  | treefold_inorder f acc1 (Branch (left, a, right)) =
    let val acc2 = f (a, acc1)
        val acc3 = treefold_inorder f acc2 left
        val acc4 = treefold_inorder f acc3 right
    in acc4 end

(* Post-order *)
and treefold_postorder f acc1 Leaf = acc1
  | treefold_postorder f acc1 (Branch (left, a, right)) =
    let val acc2 = treefold_postorder f acc1 left
        val acc3 = treefold_postorder f acc2 right
        val acc4 = f (a, acc3)
    in acc4 end
```

which Wikipedia nicely illustrates as,

[image: Source: Wikipedia's Tree traversal article]

#### Usage

```
val treelist = treefold op:: []
val treeproduct = treefold op* 1
val treecount = treefold (fn (_, count) => count + 1) 0
```

#### Extra

In-order traversal isn't meaningful if each branch/node doesn't have an *'a* value.

See also how to apply [tail-recursion on trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070577/tail-recursion-on-trees) to avoid stack overflows.

For some problems that involve tree traversal, it may be useful to supply the context of the traversal like [paramorphisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317242/what-are-paramorphisms) do:

```
fun treecata_preorder f acc1 Leaf = acc1
  | treecata_preorder f acc1 (branch as Branch (left, a, right)) =
    let val acc2 = treecata_preorder f acc1 left
        val acc3 = f (a, branch, acc2)
        val acc4 = treecata_preorder f acc3 right
    in acc4 end
```

This is a slight generalisation of `treefold_preorder` in which `f` is fed the entire `branch`.

This lets you e.g. find people in an ancestry tree for which a predicate holds for their subtree,

```
fun treefilter pred =
    treecata_preorder (fn (x, xtree, acc) => if pred xtree then x::acc else acc) []

fun branchValue Leaf = NONE
  | branchValue (Branch (_, value, _)) = SOME value

fun parents Leaf = []
  | parents (Branch (left, _, right)) =
    List.mapPartial (fn xopt => xopt) [branchValue left, branchValue right]

type name = string
type age = int
datatype person = Person of name * age

fun retired (Person (_, age)) = age >= 70
fun hasRetiredParent tree = List.exists retired (parents tree)
val personsWithRetiredParents = treefilter hasRetiredParent
```

Another neat notion for tree traversal are [zippers](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers) (LYAH chapter).

Comment: Very nice answer. I like how you seek to deepen the students understanding rather than just answer the narrow question.