# In SML why aren't you allowed real constant in pattern?

Tags: constants, sml, polyml

This code is not accepted;

```
> fun fact 0.0 = 1.0
Error-Real constants not allowed in patterns
> | fact n = n*fact(n-1);
Static Errors
```

Why is this?

Comment: See the "Comparing `real`s" part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601391/syntax-error-in-creating-a-list-from-a-tree-in-sml/40604755#40604755).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`real` is not an equality type. SML places a premium on producing provably correct code. Comparing two real numbers for equality is more often than not a bad idea since it might be the case that `x = y` *mathematically* but, because of round-off error, `x != y` at run-time. This is a notorious source of bugs in naïve implementations of numerical algorithms. Since it is so often such a bad idea, SML simply bans it. Since it thus impossible to compare an input for equality with the pattern `1.0`, it wouldn't make sense to allow it as a pattern.

In the relatively few cases that you really want to compare two reals for equality, you can use `x <= y andalso x => y`. Alternatively (as @AndreasRossberg points out), one can use the standard library function `Real.==` which is used like `Real.==(x,y)`. This last looks a bit odd, so you can declare it as an infix operator:

```
val ==  = Real.==
infix 4 ==
```

and then simply `x == y` Unfortunately neither of these can be turned into a pattern, although they do make it possible to write:

```
fun fact x = if x == 0.0 then 1.0 else x * fact(x-1.0)
```

which works as possibly intended. On the other hand, as @SimonShine points out, this will crash if you feed it any input which *isn't* of the form `n.0` where `n` is an int (even if this is only due to round-off error). This is precisely the sort of problem that the creators of SML was trying to prevent. It makes much more sense to define `fact` to take and return ints:

```
fun fact x = if x = 0 then 1 else x * fact(x-1)
```

(or -- read up on the gamma function if you really want a floating-point factorial).

This last definition can easily be converted into the pattern-matching form that you seemed to be trying for.

Comment: It may be worth noting that you also have `Real.==` if you explicitly want it.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Thank you for pointing that out. I've never had occasion to use that and had forgotten that it even exists. I added it to the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how `fun fact x = if x == 0.0 then ...` is intended to work, but if, for some reason, the input `x` is rounded the wrong way, that function will throw `Out_of_memory`. Floats should be [compared properly](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/). :-)

Comment: @SimonShine I didn't say that the intentions are good -- but if you intend to write a function which will compute the factorial of real numbers with 0 after the decimal point then that is how you would do it. This is essentially what you would do with JavaScript, which doesn't have a separate int type but just uses 64 bit floats for all numbers. Still, I should clarify.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Thanks, didn't know about the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Apparently there's a [Math.Gamma](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gamma-0.9.0.2/docs/Math-Gamma.html) Haskell package.

Comment: I think the bigger reason that `real` no longer admits equality in SML '97 is that IEEE 754, which defines floating-point numbers, defines their equality in an inconsistent way; for example, if `x` is NaN, then `Real.==(x, x)` is false! (SML '90 didn't specify how `=` would behave when given NaN, and didn't offer a separate primitive for IEEE 754 floating-point equality, so it wouldn't surprise me if some implementations handled it one way, and some implementations the other.)