# Why can't I compare reals in Standard ML?

Tags: floating-point, sml, smlnj, floating-point-comparison

1. Why doesn't `1.0 = 2.0` work? Isn't *real* an equality type?

   It gives the error:

   ```
   Error: operator and operand don't agree [equality type required]
     operator domain: ''Z * ''Z
     operand:         real * real
     in expression:
       1.0 = 2.0
   ```
2. Why won't reals in patterns work like so?

   ```
   fun fact 0.0 = 1.0
     | fact x = x * fact (x - 1.0)
   ```

   It gives the error:

   ```
   Error: syntax error: inserting  EQUALOP
   ```

Comment: Instead of making answers to this question a part of an answer to different questions, here it is more easily linkable when the question gets asked again.

Comment: [cs.SE] site has the `reference-question` tag for questions like this. Would a tag like that be helpful here?

Comment: @AntonTrunov: I don't know. It sounds useful, but I probably wouldn't have come up with using it myself. Perhaps it's a cultural thing. Maybe there is something equivalent here on the regular StackOverflow?

Comment: I tried searching, but couldn't find anything close on SO. Reference questions' job is twofold: (1) to show a standard of quality, which is expected from a question, and (2) to address some frequent/fundamental questions.

Comment: @AntonTrunov: I thought I would use the opportunity to [ask a meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340574/tag-request-reference-question), and it seems that the general opinion is that such a tag is meta, probably doesn't add much value, and isn't used consequently throughout StackOverflow anyway.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps something like this belongs on the tag wiki -- though I am not sure how many people actually read those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why doesn't `1.0 = 2.0` work? Isn't *real* an equality type?

No. The type variable `''Z` indicates that the operands of `=` must have equality types.

> Why won't reals in patterns work [...]?

Pattern matching relies implicitly on testing for equality. The cryptic error message `syntax error: inserting  EQUALOP` indicates that the SML/NJ parser does not allow for floating-point literals where a pattern is expected, and so the programmer is prevented from receiving a more meaningful type error.

To elaborate,

From http://www.smlnj.org/doc/FAQ/faq.txt:

> Q: Is real an equality type?
>
> A: It was in SML '90 and SML/NJ 0.93, but it is not in SML '97 and SML/NJ 110.
>   So `1.0 = 1.0` will cause a type error because "=" demands arguments that have an equality
>   type.  Also, real literals cannot be used in patterns.

From http://mlton.org/PolymorphicEquality:

> The one ground type that can not be compared is real. So, `13.0 = 14.0` is not type correct. One can use `Real.==` to compare reals for equality, but beware that this has different algebraic properties than polymorphic equality.

For example, `Real.== (0.1 + 0.2, 0.3)` is `false`.

From http://sml-family.org/Basis/real.html:

> Deciding if real should be an equality type, and if so, what should equality mean, was also problematic. IEEE specifies that the sign of zeros be ignored in comparisons, and that equality evaluate to false if either argument is NaN.
>
> These constraints are disturbing to the SML programmer. The former implies that 0 = ~0 is true while r/0 = r/~0 is false. The latter implies such anomalies as r = r is false, or that, for a ref cell rr, we could have rr = rr but not have !rr = !rr. We accepted the unsigned comparison of zeros, but felt that the reflexive property of equality, structural equality, and the equivalence of <> and not o = ought to be preserved.

The short version: Don't compare reals using equality. Perform an *epsilon test*. I would recommend reading the article on http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison. In summary:

- Don't check if reals are the same, but if the difference is very small.
- The error margin that the difference (*delta*) is compared to is often called *epsilon*.
- Don't compare the difference against a fixed *epsilon*:

  ```
  fun nearlyEqual (a, b, eps) = Real.abs (a-b) < eps
  ```
- Don't just compare the *relative* difference against *epsilon*:

  ```
  fun nearlyEqual (a, b, eps) = abs ((a-b)/b) < eps
  ```
- Look out for edge cases:

  - When `b = 0.0` it raises `Div`. (Switching `a` and `b` provides a symmetric edge case.)
  - When `a` and `b` are on opposite sides of zero it returns `false` even when they’re the smallest possible non-zero numbers.
  - The result is not commutative. There are cases where `nearlyEqual (a, b, eps)` does not give the same result as `nearlyEqual (b, a, eps)`.

The guide provides a generic solution; translated to Standard ML this looks like:

```
fun nearlyEqual (a, b, eps) =
    let val absA = Real.abs a
        val absB = Real.abs b
        val diff = Real.abs (a - b)
    in Real.== (a, b) orelse
     ( if Real.== (a, 0.0) orelse
          Real.== (b, 0.0) orelse
          diff < Real.minNormalPos
       then diff < eps * Real.minNormalPos
       else diff / Real.min (absA + absB, Real.maxFinite) < eps )
    end
```

And it continues to warn of some edge cases:

> There are some cases where the method above still produces unexpected results (in particular, it’s much stricter when one value is nearly zero than when it is exactly zero), and some of the tests it was developed to pass probably specify behaviour that is not appropriate for some applications. *Before using it, make sure it’s appropriate for your application!*