# Force equality for real numbers in Real in SML

Tags: types, sml, mlton

As explained in the [REAL signature](http://sml-family.org/Basis/real.html), real type defined in SML is not an equality type and hence the following expression does not reduces

```
> 1.0 = 1.0;
poly: : error: Type error in function application.
   Function: = : ''a * ''a -> bool
   Argument: (1.0, 1.0) : real * real
   Reason: Can't unify ''a to real (Requires equality type)
```

However, this is not handy as datatypes and lists containing reals, lose equality too. I would need to overload polymorphic equality `=` with `Real.==` so it could approximately consider reals too.

Is that possible ?

EDIT: Edited question to be more clear

Answer (score 3):

Did you read [Why can't I compare reals in Standard ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394992/why-cant-i-compare-reals-in-standard-ml) and consider the `Real.==` operator or perform an epsilon test? Have you considered a type like Haskell's [Data.Decimal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Decimal-0.4.2/docs/Data-Decimal.html) (in which the mantissa and exponent are handled as a pair of Integer)?

Comment: Yes, I have already read that Stack Overflow post. My question is "Can I overload `=` with `Real.==`" ? Because I need to use reals in datatypes and lists

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: no, you can't.

Comment: Thanks for the relevant answer.