# SMLNJ Insertion Sort Operator and Operand dont agree error

Tags: sml, insertion-sort, smlnj, operand

Im making an insertion sort code in SML, here it is

```
fun compare(x:real, y:real, F) = F(x, y);
fun isEqual(x:real, y:real) = ((x <= y) andalso (x >= y));

fun rinsert(x: real, [], F) = [x]
    |rinsert(x, (y::ys), F) =
    if isEqual(x, y) then rinsert (x, ys, F)
    else if compare(x, y, F) then x::y::ys
            else y::(rinsert (x, ys, F));

fun rinsort([], F) = []
    |rinsort(x::xs, F) = rinsert(x, (rinsort(xs, F), F));
```

However, on running it i get this error

```
val isEqual = fn : real * real -> bool                                                                                                                                                               
val rinsert = fn : real * real list * (real * real -> bool) -> real list                                                                                                                             
stdIn:12.27-12.58 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]                                                                                                                           
  operator domain: real * real list * (real * real -> bool)                                                                                                                                          
  operand:         'Z * ('Y list * 'X)                                                                                                                                                               
  in expression:                                                                                                                                                                                     
    rinsert (x,(rinsort (<exp>,<exp>),F))
```

I understand that rinsort is calling rinsert incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: How many arguments does `rinsert` take? How many are you calling it with?

Comment: rinsert takes three arguments, a real, a list, and an operator (like op<). It should only be calling the three

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*it should only be calling the three*". Look at the code. Count the arguments. How many are there?

Comment: Wow that was an awful oversight on my part, thanks mate. Works just fine now

Answer (score 1):

If it can be useful, This is an example of how your code should work with a`real list`:

```
fun compare(x:real, y:real, F) = F x y;
fun isEqual(x:real, y:real) = ((x <= y) andalso (x >= y));

fun rinsert(x: real, [], F) = [x]
    |rinsert(x, (y::ys), F) =
    if isEqual(x, y) then rinsert (x, ys, F)
    else if compare(x, y, F) then x::y::ys
            else y::(rinsert (x, ys, F));

fun rinsort([], F) = []
    |rinsort(x::xs, F) = rinsert(x, rinsort(xs, F), F);

val funcComp = fn r1 : real => fn r2 : real => if r1 < r2 then true else false;
val l : real list = [1.0, 3.8, 5.6, 3.8, 4.4, 5.6, 6.3, 5.5, 4.6, 8.1];
val b = rinsort(l, funcComp);
```

Comment: `if r1 > r2 then false else true` is better expressed as `r1 <= r2`.

Comment: Yes, but not exactly, because `isEqual` already check for their equality. Anyway your version is certainly better to understand.

Comment: You shouldn't be comparing reals like that. You might be interested in [Why can't I compare reals in Standard ML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394992/why-cant-i-compare-reals-in-standard-ml) Consider using `Real.==` or an epsilon test.

Answer (score 0):

Some general feedback:

- The function `compare` only serves the purpose to switch the order of the arguments of `F`, so you might as well just refer to `F` itself then.
- The function `isEqual` is kind of bad. Since [reals are not equality types in SML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394992/why-cant-i-compare-reals-in-standard-ml) for a reason, try and avoid comparing them like that. It turns out, in order to sort reals, you only need `<=`, not `=`.
- The function `rinsert` has strict `: real` type annotations that are unnecessary since your insertion sort, in taking the comparison operator `F` as a parameter, might as well be generic (polymorphic).
- You might want to call the parameter `F` something more descriptive, like `cmp`, `leq`, or whatever reminds you of its purpose.

Here's an example of how one might also make an insertion sort function:

```
fun sort leq xs =
    let fun insert (x, []) = [x]
          | insert (x, y::ys) =
              if leq (x, y)
              then x::y::ys
              else y::insert (x, ys)
    in List.foldl insert [] xs
    end
```

It has the type `('a * 'a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list`. This is comparable to e.g. SML/NJ's built-in `ListMergeSort.sort`. I've chosen `sort` to be [curried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) since you might want to specialize it by partial function application, e.g.,

```
val realsort = sort (op <=) : real list -> real list
val stringsort = sort (op >) : string list -> string list
```

but I've let the embedded helper function `insert` to be uncurried since `List.foldl` takes a function with type `('a * 'b -> 'b)`, i.e., a tuple of `(x, ys)` and returns a modified `ys` with `x` inserted.

You may want to consider which properties that can test that your function does sort. One property could be that all list elements in the sorted list are in the order specified by the comparison operator `leq`.

```
fun sorted_prop _ [] = true
  | sorted_prop _ [_] = true
  | sorted_prop leq (x::y::xs) = leq (x, y) andalso sorted_prop leq (y::xs)
```

Another property could be that each element in the unsorted list exists in the sorted list. The latter property may be hard to test if you're not assuming `x` to have an equality type (`''a`). But you could do that in the test specifically.