# Standard SML datatype list

Tags: list, types, sml

```
Datatype events = enter of string * real | exit of string *real;
```

So i have this Datatype and i have to write a function that takes a list  of events as input and return that list sorted by the real part of events.
I tried to write some functions but didnt come up with anything good, any ideas?

this is the code i tried:

```
val rec ordina = fn 
     [] => []
    |v1::v2::l => if (#2(v2)) > (#2(v1)) 
                  then ordina (v1::l)
                  else oridna (v2::1);
```

Errors i got:

poly: error: Can't find a fixed record type. Found near #2

poly: error: Can't find a fixed record type. Found near #2

Comment: What functions did you try to write? What errors did you encounter? If you want help on homework then you should show your efforts.

Comment: i posted the code i tried to use.

Comment: The `#2` macro works on tuples, but `Enter (s, r)` and `Exit (s, r)` are not directly tuples. You should make a getter function like I suggest in my answer below. Whether you use pattern matching entirely, like I suggest, or you write `fun get_... (Enter pair) = #2 pair | ...` are both options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some feedback,

- The datatype declaration should probably be

  ```
  datatype event = Enter of string * real
                 | Exit of string * real
  ```

  A single value contains a single event.

  The plural is achieved by having a value of e.g. type *event list*.

  Value constructors are usually written with an uppercase start letter.
- In SML/NJ you have a generic sort function called `ListMergeSort.sort`. It takes a function with the type *'a * 'a -> bool* where *'a = event* in this case. You could then write a function,

  ```
  fun cmp_event (event_a, event_b) = ...
  ```

  that returns whether `event_a` should be ordered before `event_b` based on their *real* parts. **Hint:** First, make a helper function that extracts the *real* part. (Come up with a better name that reflects the purpose of the real part.)

  ```
  fun get_real_part (Enter (_, r)) = ...
    | get_real_part ... = ...
  ```
- If you're not allowed to use `ListMergeSort.sort`, then [make your own sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45076156/235908).