# How to pattern match 0.0 in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I have the following code:

```
datatype complex = RealImg of real * real | Infinity;

fun divisionComplex(RealImg(a, b), RealImg(0.0, 0.0)) = Infinity
fun divisionComplex(RealImg(a, b), RealImg(c, d)) =
    RealImg ((a * c + b * d) / (c * c + d * d), ((b * c) - (a * d))/ (c* c + d * d))
```

However it fails with this:

```
Error: syntax error: inserting  EQUALOP
```

I am very confused. Why does this happen? I know that I can't compare two reals in SML, but how am I supposed to do pattern matching with 0?

Comment: This question is answered in [Why can't I compare reals in Standard ML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394992/why-cant-i-compare-reals-in-standard-ml) under **Why won't reals in patterns work [...]?** Use an epsilon.

Comment: Thanks! I've marked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said SML doesn't allow to pattern match real numbers, but recommends to use `Real.==` instead or compare the difference between these number against some delta.

What about just using a mere if statement for this? (also some `Infinity` cases added just to make the match against function params exhaustive, but feel free to change it, because it doesn't pretend to be correct)

```
datatype complex = RealImg of real * real | Infinity;

fun divisionComplex(Infinity, _) = Infinity
  | divisionComplex(_, Infinity) = Infinity
  | divisionComplex(RealImg(a, b), RealImg(c, d)) =
    if Real.== (c, 0.0) andalso Real.== (d, 0.0)
    then Infinity
    else
      RealImg ((a * c + b * d) / (c * c + d * d), ((b * c) - (a * d))/ (c* c + d * d))
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know anyway to match it without the `if then else` statement?

Comment: real number can't be matched in sml, since they are inexact and not an equality type