# How to declare inputs of a curried function as real in sml?

Tags: arguments, sml, currying, smlnj, ml

Here is my code for a curried factorial function I want the output as real

```
fun pow(x:real) (n:real)= if (n=0.0) then 1.0 else x:real*pow(x:real) (n-1:real) ;
```

But my syntax is really really wrong how do I fix this?

Comment: The following Q&A: [Why can't I compare reals in Standard ML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394992/why-cant-i-compare-reals-in-standard-ml) has the `real` factorial function as its example (although rewritten into pattern matching). But I admit ruakh's `real` solution below which avoids the comparison is pretty neat, too.

Comment: Why not use the built-in `Math.pow : real * real -> real`, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
fun pow x n =
  if n = 0
  then 1.0
  else x * pow x (n - 1)
```

or, if you want to be a bit more explicit about the types:

```
fun pow (x : real) (n : int) : real =
  if n = 0
  then 1.0
  else x * pow x (n - 1)
```

That is:

- I think you want `n` to be of type `int`, not type `real`. (Your approach only makes sense if `n` is a nonnegative integer, since otherwise the recursion would just go forever.)
- You don't need so many `:real`-s everywhere; they don't add anything, because the compiler can infer the types.