# SML: tree reduce with a base and a composition function

Tags: tree, reduce, sml, folding

I want to reduce a binary tree with a base value z, a combining function g. This function has to have work of O(n) but a span of O(log n).
Tree is defined as `datatype tree = Leaf of int | Node of tree * tree`.

This is my code

```
treeReduce : ('a * 'a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a tree -> 'a
Requires: g is associative, z is an identity of g
Ensures: treereduce g z T ~= foldr g z (inord T) ~= foldl g z (inord T)

fun treeReduce (g: 'a * 'a -> 'a) (z : 'a) (Empty: 'a tree)=z
  | treeReduce g z (Node(l,x,r))=g(g(treeReduce g z l,x),treeReduce g z r)
```

However this doesn't produce the correct answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What functions and inputs are you testing it with, and what are the expected and actual outputs?

Comment: Your type definition does not match your function's type.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your code doesn't produce the correct answer, but you don't say what answer you get and why this isn't correct. So perhaps there's a bug in your code, or perhaps you're traversing the tree in another order than you want. If I were to find out, I'd reformat your code slightly:

```
fun treeReduce g z0 Empty = z0
  | treeReduce g z0 (Node (left, x, right)) =
    let val z1a = treeReduce g z0 left
        val z1b = treeReduce g z0 right
        val y = g (z1a, x)
        val z = g (z1b, y)
    in z end
```

I've used a *let-in-end* to more accurately give each calculation a name.

- One thing that strikes me as odd is that `z1a` and `z1b` are both based on `z0`. Compare this to the implementation of [preorder, inorder and postorder traversal of trees in SML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636618/235908) and you'll see that you probably want the accumulated value to travel along each node. In your case, `z1a` is not carried to the `right` branch.
- Another thing that strikes me as odd is `treeReduce`'s type signature:

  ```
  ('a * 'a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a tree -> 'a
  ```

  Compare this to `treefold_preorder`'s:

  ```
  ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a tree -> 'b
  ```

  and for that sake, `List.foldl`'s:

  ```
  ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
  ```

  This allows for the accumulating function to produce values of arbitrary type `'b` instead of only being able to produce values of the tree's node type, `'a`. This presumably accidental variation is caused by feeding `g`'s output to itself:

  ```
  g(g(tree..., x), tree...)
  ```

  forcing its input value (the node type, `'a`) to have the same type as its output value.

> What am I doing wrong?

You're gluing the left and right calls to `treeReduce` together the wrong way, and you have one call to `g` too many (in the attempt to glue together the left and right calls to `treeReduce`), causing it to have type `'a * 'a -> 'a` when you want it to have type `'a * 'b -> 'b` or similar.

---

Since you're folding trees, this may be of interest:

- [Tail-recursion on trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070577/tail-recursion-on-trees)