# Convert recursive binary tree traversal to iterative

Tags: c, recursion, iteration, binary-tree, imperative-programming

I was asked to write the iterative version, but I wrote the recursive version i.e.

```
void inorderTraverse(BinaryTree root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        printf("%d",root->id);
    else
    {
        inorderTraverse(root->left);
        printf("%d",root->id);
        inorderTraverse(root->right);
    }
}
```

I'm not looking for the code, I want to understand how this can be done. Had it been just the last recursive call, I would have done

```
void inorderTraverse(BinaryTree root)
{
    while(root!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",root->id);
        root=root->right;
    }
}
```

But **how do I convert to an iterative program when there are two recursive calls?**

Here are the type definitions.

```
struct element{
    struct element* parent;
    int id;
    char* name;
    struct element* left;
    struct element* right;
};
typedef element* BinaryTree;
```

This is what I thought of, am I on the right track?

```
temp=root;
while(1)
{
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
     push(s,temp);
     temp=temp->left;
     continue;
    }

    temp=pop(s);
    if(temp==NULL)
    return;
    printf("%d\t",temp->data);
    temp=temp->right;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `BinaryTree` interface? Is it possible to get the parent of a tree node?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can every recursion be converted into iteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/931762/), [Design patterns for converting recursive algorithms to iterative ones](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549943/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is that you need to "remember" the *last place* you were iterating at.
When doing recursion, the program internally uses "the stack" to remember where to go back to.
But when doing iteration, it doesn't.

Although... does that give you an idea?

Comment: i know it has got something to do with pushing the things on stack and then popping them, but i really cant figure this out, like what to push, when to pop, and how.

Comment: ok, i can start by pushing all the nodes, till i reach the leftmost leaf, now after that i start popping,now after popping first one, i push the right child on stach, and keep pushing till i reach the leftmost leaf of this subtree, now i go to the right tree, and reach the right most leaf of that subtree, but now how would i know how much pops do i need to do so that i reach the parent of the leftmost leaf of the original tree?

Comment: kindly help me out a bit more with the stack thing, if you can.

Comment: @Karan: I'm not sure if I quite followed what you mentioned, but what you want to do is to do this: (1) push the current node and keep pushing its left children as many times as you can (i.e. until there is no left node), (2) pop the last node (this has the return value), (3) repeat step 1 with the right child, if any, of the last node you popped.

Comment: @Karan: I'm not sure why you have `if(temp==NULL)` in your code -- you never push a `NULL`, so why should you pop a `NULL`? Or is that supposed to signal an emptiness condition? But aside from that, it seems fine... have you tried it?

Comment: it does not give the right sequence, i dont think i am able to go up the tree.

Comment: yeah, that is for checking the emptiness. But, i m not getting the desired result. Inorder traversal is not achieved.

Comment: and why should it, because after i reach the left most leaf of any subtree, i am just popping once, that takes me one step higher in the tree, i dont think, i will be ever able to traverse up by more that one node. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @Karan: I just tested your program in another language and it ran fine. Are you sure your tree is correct? What output do you get?

Comment: sorry it was correct, i thought it to out =put the wrong order. Thanks.

Comment: and yeah , i get it how i would be able to go up the tree, since when i pop the node, it no longer stays in the stack(obviously) and the next time pop the node, it takes me one step ahead. So i guess, the way to go from recursive to iterative is that, you see how your stack is going to behave and accordingly implement it, right?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a *really* elegant way to do this iteratively off-hand.

One possibility might be using a 'mark algorithm', where you start out with all nodes 'unmarked' and 'mark' nodes as they're handled. The markers can be added to the object model or kept in a seperate entity.

Pseudocode:

```
for (BinaryTree currentNode = leftmostNode(root); currentNode != null; currentNode = nextNode(currentNode)):
  print currentNode;
  currentNode.seen = true;

sub nextNode(BinaryTree node):
  if (!node.left.seen):
    return leftmostNode(node.left)
  else if (!node.seen)
    return node
  else if (!node.right.seen)
    return leftmostNode(node.right)
  else 
    return nextUnseenParent(node)

sub leftmostNode(BinaryTree node):
  while (node.left != null)
    node = node.left
  return node;

sub nextUnseenParent(BinaryTree node):
  while (node.parent.seen)
    node = node.parent
  return node.parent
```

Comment: i was also going for something like this only,
But this does count as an iterative version right?

Comment: also, i dont think this is an inorder traversal, as for the matter of fact, you started printing from the root.

Comment: The 'iteration step' is a bit more complicated than usual, but it contains only `for` loops, `while` loops and no recursive calls, so I'd say it should qualify as iterative.

Answer (score 0):

I take it for granted, that *iterating* down from the parent nodes to the left nodes is not a problem. The problem is to know what to do when going up from one node to the parent: should you take the right child node or should you go up one more parent?

The following trick will help you:

Before going upwards remember the current node. Then go upwards. Now you can compare: Have you been in the left node: Then take the right node. Otherwise go up one more parent node.

You need only one reference/pointer for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general way of converting recursive traversal to iterator by using a lazy iterator which concatenates multiple iterator suppliers (lambda expression which returns an iterator). See my [Converting Recursive Traversal to Iterator](http://www.cnblogs.com/weidagang2046/p/lazy-iterator.html).