# Recursive Fib style function into Iterative?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, integer, iteration

I have a function in java which is written with a recursive algorithm that needs to be written in Iterative form. The thing is that I dont know where to start in wrapping my mind around a new algorithm for this. This is an assignment I am working on.

Consider the following computational problem:

Suppose you work as a consultant and you have a sequence of `n` potential consulting jobs that pay `A[0],A[1],..,A[n-1]` dollars, respectively (so job `0` pays `A[0]` dollars, job `1` pays `A[1]` dollars, etc.).

Also, job `i` starts on day `i` `(i = 0 ; : : : ; n   1 )`.

However, each job requires 2 days, so you cannot perform any two consecutive jobs. The goal is to determine the maximum amount of money, denoted by `F(n)` ; you can earn from a valid job schedule selected from the `n` jobs `A[0]` through `A[n-1]`
:
As an example, consider the following input array:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
A 5 6 8 6 2 4
```

An optimal schedule is to do jobs `0 ; 2 ;` and `5` ; for which the amount of money
earned, `F(6) = A[0] + A [2] + A [5] = 17` ; is as large as possible. Notice that this
is a valid schedule, as no two consecutive jobs are included.

My function for the recursive version that solves this is as follows:

```
public static int jobScheduleRecursive(int[] A, int n) 
{
    n = A.length;
    if(n == 0){return 0;}
    else if(n == 1){return A[0];}
    else if(n >= 2){return max(jobScheduleRecursive(A, (n-1)), (A[n-1]) 
                           + jobScheduleRecursive(A, n-2));}
    else return -1;
}
```

To sum up, I have to come up with an iterative algorithm that does this job. The only problem is that i have no idea how to proceed. I would appreciate any advice to lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Why do you take an argument and then immediately set its value? Why take it in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can every recursion be converted into iteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/931762/), [Design patterns for converting recursive algorithms to iterative ones](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549943/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes, iterative solutions for a known recursive solution to problems isn't straight forward as the recursive solution. The easiest way to achieve iterative solution is to use  - [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) basically what you want is to create a temporary array that holds the solution to all sub-problems in the way. to achieve that, create a dynamically allocated array in the size of your input. and if for instance your recursive function is int foo(int a)
fill the array with the solutions to 1..n, where n is the input for your original problem.
change the algorithm, that instead of calling itself recursivelly, it will check if the solution for the sub-problem allready exists in the array, if not, it fills it up. that way a sub-problem won't compute numerus times, but only once.