# Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

Tags: php, xdebug

I want to create a crawler who take the informations of all pages one by one from number 0 to 10 000 000. I don't matter how much time it takes. I just want it works. Here is the error i obtain

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in D:\wamp\www\crawler\index.php on line 25
```

The line 25 is

```
$htmlstr = (string)$this->curlGet($url);
```

And there is my complete script.

Thank you for your help !

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
ini_set('max_input_nesting_level','100000');
ini_set('max_execution_time','100000'); 

class crawler{

    private $url;
    private $page;
    private $bothurl;
    private $innerDom = null;
    public $prop;
    public $entry;

    function __construct($entry){
        $this->entry = $entry;
        $this->bothurl = array('http://www.remax-quebec.com/fr/inscription/Q/'.$entry.'.rmx','http://www.remax-quebec.com/en/inscription/Q/'.$entry.'.rmx');
        $this->scan();
    }

    private function scan(){
        $i =0;
        foreach($this->bothurl as $url){
            $this->url = $url;
            $this->lang = ($i==0)?'fr':'en';
            $htmlstr = (string)$this->curlGet($url);
            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            @$dom->loadHTML($htmlstr);
            $this->page = $dom;
            $this->htmlInfos();
            $this->getInfos();
            $i++;
        }
    }

    private function htmlInfos(){
        $divs = $this->page->getElementsByTagName('div');
        foreach($divs as $div){
            if($div->hasAttribute('class') && $div->getAttribute('class') == 'bloc specs'){
                $innerDom = new DOMDocument(); 
                @$innerDom->loadHTML($this->innerHTML($div));
                $this->innerDom = $innerDom;
            }
        }
        if($this->innerDom === null) $this->changeEntry();
    }

    private function getInfos(){
        $sect = 0;

        foreach($this->innerDom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div){
        # obtenir la description
             $this->getDesc($div->getAttribute('class'),$div);
        # obtenir les caractéristiques
             $this->getCaract($div->getAttribute('class'),$div);
        # obtenir les informations interieur, exterieur et evaluation
             if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'section deux-colonnes'){
                switch($sect){
                    case 0: $this->getSpecInfos($div,'interieur'); break;
                    case 1: $this->getSpecInfos($div,'exterieur'); break;
                    case 2: $this->getSpecInfos($div,'evaluation'); break;
                    case 3: $this->getSpecInfos($div,'equipement'); break;
                    case 4: $this->getSpecInfos($div,'services'); break;
                }
                $sect++;
             }else if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'section'){
        # obtenir les détails des pièces
                foreach($div->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table){
                    if($table->getAttribute('class') == 'details-pieces'){
                        $this->detailPieces($table);
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    }

    private function getDesc($class,$obj){
        if($class == 'section description'){
            $p = $obj->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
            $text = (string)$p->nodeValue;
            $this->prop[$this->lang]['description'] = $text;
        }
    }

    private function getCaract($class,$obj){
        if($class == 'section characteristiques'){
            foreach($obj->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div){
                if(substr($div->getAttribute('class'),0,4) == "item"){
                    $text = (string)$div->nodeValue;
                    $this->prop[$this->lang]['caracteritiques'][substr($div->getAttribute('class'),5)] = $text;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function getSpecInfos($obj,$nomInfo){
        foreach($obj->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table){
            foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
                $name = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0);
                $value = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(1);
                $name = substr((string)$name->nodeValue,0,-2);
                $value = (string)$value->nodeValue;
                $this->prop[$this->lang][$nomInfo][$this->noAccents($name)] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    private function detailPieces($obj){
        $tbody = $obj->getElementsByTagName('tbody')->item(0);
        foreach($tbody->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
            $name = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0);
            $name = (string)$name->nodeValue;
            $level = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(1);
            $level = (string)$level->nodeValue;
            $dimensions = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(2);
            $dimensions = (string)$dimensions->nodeValue;
            $floor = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(3);
            $floor = (string)$floor->nodeValue;
            $desc = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(4);
            $desc = (string)$desc->nodeValue;

            $this->prop[$this->lang]['pieces'][$this->noAccents($name)]['etage'] = $level;
            $this->prop[$this->lang]['pieces'][$this->noAccents($name)]['dimensions'] = $dimensions;
            $this->prop[$this->lang]['pieces'][$this->noAccents($name)]['revetement'] = $floor;
            $this->prop[$this->lang]['pieces'][$this->noAccents($name)]['description'] = $desc;
        }
    }

    private function innerHTML($element){ 
        $innerHTML = ""; 
        $children = $element->childNodes; 
        foreach ($children as $child) 
        { 
            $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
            $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
            $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
        } 
        return $innerHTML; 
    }

    private function noAccents($value){
        $string= strtr($chaine,"ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ","aaaaaaaaaaaaooooooooooooeeeeeeeecciiiiiiiiuuuuuuuuynn");
    }

    private function changeEntry(){
        $this->entry++;
        echo $this->entry;
        $this->scan();
    }

    private function curlGet($url){
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $data;
    }
}

$entry = 8678057;

$crawler = new crawler($entry);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($crawler->prop);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I don't really see effort here to try to understand the issue.

Comment: You've got an error. That's nice. You've posted code. That's also nice, but where is your question? Do you want us to magically fix your code and post a working solution here?

Comment: Don't do this recursively. [Rewrite it iteratively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549943/design-patterns-for-converting-recursive-algorithms-to-iterative-ones).

Comment: If you write code, you're a programmer. Don't be so hard on yourself. Yes, the easier way is [Martin.'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10157667/139010), but it's not (what I would call) the Right Answer.

Comment: i'm not very good in maths, i'm not a programmer, i am a web integrator. Do you have a easier way in php ? Thank you for your help ^^

Comment: But i want to learn how to make better coding. U have a tutorial where i can learn that ?

Comment: No, i just want to know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Did you read the answers to the question I linked?

Comment: Yes, but it's not in php, i fund a post in another blog where it explain it in php ! Thank you very much man

Comment: its because of the xdebug setting. see the other answer with: ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', $limit)

Comment: If you only want examples of crawling, have a look at http://scraperwiki.com.  It is a site collecting user-contributed scraping scripts in a few languages (php,ruby,python) and gives a re-usable format from their site. I think it may be usefull to you. If you are not programmer yourself, you may find working and concrete examples there.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming you're using xdebug, you can set your own limit with

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', $limit)
```

Comment: Using assetic with a plugin for less.php in laravel 4 to compile bootstrap, I hit the 100 max error, increasing to 200 allows it to run. Seems legit.

Answer (score 3):

changes the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf parameter to something like that 
max_allowed_packet = 512M

Get sure you've got xdebug installed (use phpinfo()) and then change the file /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini adding or editing the line :
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000

Restart both services
sudo service mysql restart
sudo service php5-fpm restart

If it doesn't work you can still set those two parameters to false at /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini 
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was related to composer. Some vendors were updated in the **composer.json** file, but I forgot to run the commands **composer update** nor **composer install**. The system generated a cascade of errros, which was causing this 'maximum nested level'.

After executing those commands, the problem was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't make a drop-dead halt mistake, just change the limit of xdebug.

I sloved this problem by changed the **xdebug.ini** file. (In my mac, the path is */usr/local/php5-5.6.17-20160108-103504/php.d/50-extension-xdebug.ini*, maybe yours would be a little different. )

Add a new line at the bottom of xdebug.ini file:

> xdebug.max_nesting_level=500

---

Remember: *You must change the xdebug.ini corresponding to the php you are using*. For example, if you installed php5 and xampp in your computer, you need to figure out which php you're using.