# Cakephp giving Fatal error in my local computer

Tags: cakephp, fatal-error

I have a projects in cakephp which is a big size projects.. It is running perfectly in another computer or in the server. But when I copy the files and database to my local computer then it shows the following error.

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in D:\wamp\www\faceadz\cake\libs\debugger.php on line 248
```

Project is running in wamp server.

Please help me...

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157649/maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-aborting

Answer (score 2):

there might be 2 solution will work for you in you local machine configuration

**1.** A simple solution solved to your problem. you can just commented the:

```
"zend_extension = "d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"
```

in your php.ini file. This extension was limiting the stack to 100 so I disabled it. The recursive function is now working as anticipated.

**2.** and

Assuming you're using xdebug, you can set your own limit with

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', $limit)
```

**EDIT**

Also it will help you

changes the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf parameter to something like that max_allowed_packet = 512M

Get sure you've got xdebug installed (use phpinfo()) and then change the file /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini adding or editing the line : xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000

Restart both services sudo service mysql restart sudo service php5-fpm restart

If it doesn't work you can still set those two parameters to false at /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini xdebug.remote_autostart=0 xdebug.remote_enable=0

hope it will help you,