# 'Too much recursion'-error in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, console.log

I am trying to learn Typescript in combination with some exercises. I can't figure out why I am getting this error of too much recursion. I made some wrapper-functions.

#### Wrapper-functions

```
type Fun<a,b> = {
   f: (i:a) => b
   then: <c>(g:Fun<b,c>) => Fun<a,c>
}

let myFunction = function<a,b>(f:(_:a) => b) : Fun<a,b> {
    return {
       f:f,
       then: function<c>(this:Fun<a,b>, g:Fun<b,c>) : Fun<a,c> {
           return then(this,g);
       }
    }
};

let then = function<a,b,c>(f: Fun<a,b>, g:Fun<b,c>) : Fun<a,c> {
    return myFunction(a => g.f(f.f(a)))
};
```

I'd like to create my own RepeatFunction so to say, whereas I can pass a function and an amount of executes as parameters.

#### My code

```
let increase = myFunction<number,number>(x => x + 1);

let RepeatFunction = function<a>(f: Fun<a,a>, n: number) : Fun<a,a> {
   if (n < 0)
   {
       return myFunction(x => f.f(x));
   }
   else
   {
       for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           RepeatFunction(myFunction<a,a>(x => this.f(x)), n); //error in console
       }
   }
};

console.log(RepeatFunction(increase, 2).f(10));
```

I'd like to call RepeatFunction, pass in my increase-function with to execute 2 times on number 10.

I am getting the error: 'Too much recursion'. Could anyone tell me what I am missing here? There are no syntax errors.

### edit 2

```
let RepeatFunction = function<a>(f: Fun<a,a>, n: number) : Fun<a,a> {
   if (n < 0)
   {
       return myFunction(x => f.f(x));
   }
   else
   {
       return RepeatFunction(myFunction<a,a>(x => f.f(x)), n - 1);
   }
};

console.log(RepeatFunction(incr, 1).f(10));  // answer is: 11
console.log(RepeatFunction(incr, 5).f(10));  // answer is: 11
console.log(RepeatFunction(incr, 50).f(10)); // answer is: 11
```

Comment: repeat = RepeatFunction, thank you for noticing. Edited my post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a stack-safe chainRec operator for the continuation monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967530/how-to-implement-a-stack-safe-chainrec-operator-for-the-continuation-monad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this is infinitely recursive because `n` never changes in value, you always call `RepeatFunction` with the same `n`. My guess is you want to call it `n` times, so you should decrease `n` next time you call it, or you can use an iterative version :

```
let RepeatFunction = function<a>(f: Fun<a,a>, n: number) : Fun<a,a> {
    if (n < 1)
    {
        return myFunction(x => f.f(x));
    }
    else
    {
        var fn = myFunction<a,a>((x) => f.f(x));
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            fn = fn.then(f);
        }
        return fn;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My result in console is: 'TypeError: RepeatFunction(...) is undefined'

Comment: @J.Doe There were other issues in the code, fixed them now

Comment: (see edit 2) Ty, it runs now but I don't get the expected output. I doesn't matter whether I change the n in my function call, I always get 11 as result. But it should increment n times on number 10.

Comment: @J.Doe Yeah, I saw that too, mu guess is you want `f(f(f.. n times... f(0))` added a non recursive version for that