# Much frustrated gnashing from undefined function return type

Tags: javascript, recursion, undefined

My experience with recursive calls is not deep or long, but I thought this problem would make for a good evaluation. Most of it appears to work, but the function returns undefined:

```
const target = 1234; // count the number of digits

function numDigits(num, count=0){
     let div10 = count;
     div10 += 1;

     if(Math.floor(num / 10) < 1){
          console.log(`Entered the end and div10 is ${div10}`);
          return div10; // returning undefined
     }

     let curr = Math.floor(num / 10);
     console.log(`Bottom of call and dividing ${curr}`);

     numDigits(curr, div10);

}

numDigits(target);
```

Answer (score 4):

You miss a `return` when calling recursively `numDigits`:

```js
const target = 1234; // count the number of digits

function numDigits(num, count=0){
     let div10 = count;
     div10 += 1;

     if(Math.floor(num / 10) < 1){
          console.log(`Entered the end and div10 is ${div10}`);
          return div10; // returning undefined
     }

     let curr = Math.floor(num / 10);
     console.log(`Bottom of call and dividing ${curr}`);

     return numDigits(curr, div10); // HERE

}

console.log(numDigits(target));
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I understand what is happening, as up until the 3rd recursive call, things appeared to work, and that was without the return. Can you elaborate on why that made it work?

Comment: calls heppen, they do. But if you don't execute `return` as I added, then your func will not return anything. Does it make sense now?

Comment: *return* isn't called (it's not a function), it's executed. ;-)

Comment: I sort of get it: the recursive call at some point has to return something. In my initial code, that wasn't happening. Thanks.

Comment: @jobechoi—yes, the issue is that the function only returns a value if the *if* block is executed, in every other case it just returns *undefined*. So if that block is executed on any call other than the first, it returns *undefined*.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. There's no *"missing `return`"*; there's little need for `return` in functional style as it is a side effect, it does not produce a value, it cannot be called like a function, and it cannot be combined with other expressions. Other imperative style statements like the reassignment/mutation `div10 += 1` are also a recipe for a migraine when used recursively.

Your program can be dramatically simplified –

```js
const numDigits = n =>
  n < 10
    ? 1
    : 1 + numDigits (Math .floor (n / 10))
        
console .log
  ( numDigits (1)         // 1
  , numDigits (22)        // 2
  , numDigits (333)       // 3
  , numDigits (999999999) // 9
  )
```

The `count` variable can still be used if you prefer. This would be a practical step toward making the program stack-safe –

```js
const numDigits = (n, count = 1) =>
  n < 10
    ? count
    : numDigits
        ( Math .floor (n / 10)
        , count + 1
        )
        
console .log
  ( numDigits (1)         // 1
  , numDigits (22)        // 2
  , numDigits (333)       // 3
  , numDigits (999999999) // 9
  )
```

Comment: "*There's no "missing return"*" might be a reasonable statement if you hadn't added an implicit return through use of an arrow function. There is indeed a missing return statement, your refactored code is effectively `if (n < 10) {return count} else {return numDigits(Math.floor (n / 10), count + 1)}`. Removing the redundant *else* but keeping the return statement in the block is effectively identical to the OP's code. QED.

Comment: The ternary is simple and succinct. As stated: new to recursion. I will keep this model in mind now. I see that my departure happened much earlier, even before the code was written: I never thought to check whether the integer was less than 10. Thanks, user633183.

Comment: @RobG the difference lies between statements and expressions – statements like `if`, `else`, `foreach`, `switch`, `while`, and `return` are *side effects*, do not produce a value, and cannot be composed with other statements. Worse, `if` allows you to write conditionals without an `else` branch – ternary *expressions* using `?:` evaluate to a value, can be composed with other expressions, and cannot be written without an "else" branch. It looks like I never got around to finishing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46463482/633183) but I think you will find it useful.

Comment: @RobG and for more about discussion about statements vs. expressions, I wish to share [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51389434/633183). Any further discussion is welcomed and encouraged. The topics here are among my favourite :D